# How To Convert From Scientific To Number Value While Writing Excel In Apache Poi Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to create an XL sheet using Apache POI with some values which are long numeric for ex:1234567891011.

When i use below sample code to generate the excel sheet, the data is  stored in form of Scientific format (1.23457E+12). But i want to  store this data as a number ex. 1234567891011.00 is fine.

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("format sheet");
String str = "1234567891011";
Row row;
Cell cell;
short rowNum = 0;
short colNum = 0;

row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
cell = row.createCell(colNum);
cell.setCellValue(str);


FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

I  tried to set the cell format to Numeric as below code but  doesnt work.

```
row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
cell = row.createCell(colNum);
cell.setCellValue(str);
dateCell1.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
double converted = new Double(str);
dateCell1.setCellValue(converted);
```

Please tell if any way possible to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Excel` is using number format `General` per default. This switches to scientific format if needed. That means if cell width is too small or numeric value is too big.

So do using a cell style having a special number format `0.00` or `0`.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelBigDecimal {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xls";

  DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();

  CellStyle numberCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  numberCellStyle.setDataFormat((short)8);
  numberCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.00"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);

  double value = 1234567891011d;

  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(numberCellStyle);

  sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 20*256);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

That leads to showing `1234567891011.00` in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the cell as String type and format your number java side.

```
long yourLongNumber = 1234567891011;
String strLong = String.format("%d", yourLongNumber);
//out: "1234567891011"
```